# How to restore armor stands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was building a map with a lot of custom armor stands and I accidentally used the `/kill @e` command. Is there any way I can restore my armor stands?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot undo any commands in Minecraft. `/kill @e` is a command therefore it cannot be undone.

Comment: I don't believe so.